# javascript on option button wont work in cakephp3

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I cant get  javascript code to work in cakephp3. Originally I want to hide/show a div section from clicking an option. The project works fine apart from this js function. I have the js function in a file (webroot/js/myjs.js) and I call the file in the layout as below. I click an option button to invoke this function to test it and I get no output. I cant see what else I need to do as I am stuck.

```
    http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-inline-javascript-blocks

<?php 

  $options=array(0=>'Student',1=>'Tutor');
    echo $this->Form->input('cancelledBy',
           [ 'label'=>false,  'style'=>"margin:10px;",  'type' => 'radio',   'options' => $options,
                        'onclick'=>'hide()', 'value'=>0]);

                ?>

      <div id="cancel" style="display: none;">Hello hidden content</div>


//myjs.js
  <script type="text/javascript">
function hide()
{
 alert('asd');



    var e = document.getElementById("cancel");

      if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';



}
</script> 


//layoutfile (which appears when i see the page source with the javascript function
 <?php echo $this->Html->script(['myjs.js']); ?>
```

Comment: Your code looks all good..is that alert showing ? And is console showing some error ?

Comment: I tried the answer suggestion and this didnt work and no the alert doesnt fire either. I really dont get what to do so I have a public copy  http://crm5.aptutoring.com.au/lessons/cancelledlessontest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in your view `$this->Html->script('myjs', ['block' => 'scriptBottom']);`
and add this `<?= $this->fetch('scriptBottom') ?>` to your layout before `</body>`

**EDIT**

remove `'type' => 'radio'` and change onclick event for onchange

```
$options = array(0=>'Student',1=>'Tutor');

echo $this->Form->input('cancelledBy', [
    'label' => false,  
    'style' => "margin:10px;",  
    'options' => $options,
    'onchange' => 'hide()',
]);
```

Comment: This didnt work either. I must be missing something http://crm5.aptutoring.com.au/lessons/cancelledlessontest

Comment: apparently onclick isn't working for radio butons, check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

//in view

```
echo $this->Form->input('cancelledBy', [
    'class' => 'cancelledByClass', 
    'label' => false, 
    'style' => "margin:10px;", 
    'type' => 'radio',   
    'options' => $options,
    'value' => 0
]);
```

//      js

```
$('input[name="cancelledBy"]').change(function(){
  alert('Here');
  var e = document.getElementById("cancel");

  if (e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';
  else
    e.style.display = 'block';
});
```